# I can't get jQueryRotate to work with IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation, rotation

This question replaces a previous one I posted a few days ago. I have rewritten my code, removing HTML5 Canvas altogether.

I am struggling to get jQueryRotate to work with IE. My code works in Firefox and IE9 but getting a

```
'parentNode' is null or not an object - in IE8.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/otherDewi/pm4Ng/2/

XHair, yHair position the crosshairs, and the rest of the code in the mousemove function calculates the angle of the gun.

```
    $wrapper.mousemove(function(e){
    xHair=e.pageX-45;
    yHair=e.pageY-45;
    xGPos    = xHair/4+280;
    yGPos    = yHair/4+200;
    difx     = xHair-(190+xGPos);
    dify     = yHair -(185+ yGPos); 
    radians  = Math.atan2(dify,difx);
    //rotation = radians+2.36; //rotation in radians
    rotation = (((radians*180)/Math.PI)+135); //rotation in degrees
    //console.log(rotation);
});
```

On jsFiddle the code works if either of the $gun.rotate lines are commented out

```
    function shotGun(){
    //$gun.rotate({angle:rotation});
    //$gun.rotate({angle:45});         
    $gun.css('margin-left', xHair/4+280);
    $gun.css('margin-top', yHair/4+200);
}
```